# Trying to create a function that takes two long values and returns true if and only if the first value is a multiple of the second value

Tags: java, boolean

I'm having difficulty understanding why this function is behaving incorrectly.

If I make the value of num1 10 and the value of num2 20, when run, the program tells me that 10 is a value of 20 when in fact it isn't. When I switch the values around and make num1 20 and num2 10, it tells me that num1 is a multiple of num2 - which is correct.

If anyone can explain to me where I'm going wrong and if they could show me a corrected version of the code (if possible), it would be greatly appreciated!

```
public class Multiple {

    public static void main(String[]args) {
        boolean multiple = true;

        while(multiple = true) {
            long num1 = 10;
            long num2 = 20;
            boolean result = isMultiple(num1, num2);

            if (result = true) {
                System.out.println(num1 + " is a multiple of " + num2);
            } else {
                System.out.println(num2 + " is not a multiple of " + num1);
            }
            break;
        }
    }

    public static boolean isMultiple(long x, long y) {
        if (x % y == 0) {
                return true;
        } else if (y % x == 0) {
            return false;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: The problem is the if condition `result = true` which should be `result == true`. With your implementation this will always be true, because you assign `true` to the variable `result`. Thus, everything will be a multiple of every other thing.

Comment: Also, swapping the order of `num1` and `num2` in your messaging is likely to cause confusion.

Comment: There is no need to write (or to attempt to write) `if (result == true) {`: using `if (result) {` is more concise and avoids the risk of using `=` instead of `==`.

Comment: Also your while loop is pointless.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The line `if (result = true)` is actually *setting* `result` to `true`.  It should be changed to `result == true`.  I'm not sure about the purpose of the while loop, but I know that the `isMultiple` method can definitely be streamlined.  Anyway, I corrected the `if` condition and did some other refactoring.

```
public class Multiple {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        long num1 = 10;
        long num2 = 20;

        if (isMultiple(num1, num2)) {
            System.out.println(num1 + " is a multiple of " + num2);
        } else {
            // num1 should come before num2 here
            System.out.println(num1 + " is not a multiple of " + num2);
        }
    }

    public static boolean isMultiple(long x, long y) {

        // check that x is a multiple of y
        return x % y == 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your feedback! However, It's still telling me that 10 is a multiple of 20 when it isn't. Any suggestions?

Comment: @ChrisMulheron I made a mistake earlier in `isMultiple`, which I've since edited.  Make sure that yours says `return x % y == 0;`, specifically check the order of `x` and `y`.

Comment: Thank you very much! That seems to be working correctly now.

Answer (score 1):

You code should be like :

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    boolean multiple = true;
    while(multiple) {
        long num1 = 10;
        long num2 = 20;
        boolean result = isMultiple(num1, num2);
        if(result){
            System.out.println(num1 + " is a multiple of " + num2);
        } else {
            System.out.println(num1 + " is not a multiple of " + num2);
        }
        break;
    }
}

public static boolean isMultiple(long x, long y){
    if (y%x == 0) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Changes = true in if and while is not needed. Also for the first num to be multiple of second you need to doe second num % first number. You don't need a loop but i think you have it cause you might want it later on so i'm keeping it.

Comment: What's wrong with `return (y%x == 0);` in `isMultiple`?

Comment: isMultiple() could just be: `return y % x == 0;`  And no while loop is required.

Comment: Dammit Carl, we keep writing the same comments!

Comment: I have revised my code, thanks for the correction! I have added your corrected code to my program, however I am still getting the incorrect output. When I use 10 as num1 and 20 as num2, it still says that 10 is a multiple of 20, when it's not. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    boolean multiple = true;
    while(multiple) {
        long num1 = 10;
        long num2 = 20;
        boolean result = isMultiple(num1, num2);
        if(result){
            System.out.println(num1 + " is a multiple of " + num2);
        } else {
            System.out.println(num1 + " is not a multiple of " + num2);
        }
        break;
    }
}

public static boolean isMultiple(long x, long y){
        if (x<y) return false;
        return (x % y == 0);
}
```